# Update Set column only if its NULL else move to next column and so on update with same data

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, case

I want to update a column when it's only `NULL`, else update the same data in the next column and so on.

I don't want to write 4 IF conditions, can it be possible in single CASE like below?

Below is something I am trying to achieve.

```
UPDATE I 
        SET 
        (CASE 
            WHEN I."CA_Status1" ISNULL THEN I."CA_Status1"
            WHEN I."CA_Status1" IS NOTNULL THEN I."CA_Status2"
            WHEN I."CA_Status2" IS NOTNULL THEN I."CA_Status3"
            WHEN I."CA_Status3" IS NOTNULL THEN I."CA_Status4"
            END
            )
            = "7".StatusCode

        ,I."ENC" = "7".ActionCode

        FROM [dbo].[Out_P] I 
        INNER JOIN #TempOut_P "7" 
        ON I.ID = "7".Number
```

Comment: `I."CA_Status1" = NULL` isn't going to work, nothing equals `NULL`, including `NULL`. If you need to compare a value to `NULL` then you need to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`.

Comment: Also, you can't use a `CASE` expression to replace the name of a column. It's `SET <Column Name> = <Expression>`. If you have (up to) 4 columns to `UPDATE`, you need 4 assignment statements in the `SET`: `SET <Column Name> = <Expression>, <Column Name> = <Expression>, ...`

Comment: made the changes, so you mean i can only write 4 different case statements? thats the only solution

Comment: It's a `CASE` **expression**. And I don't really follow what you are *actually* trying to achieve. Sample data and expected results, in a **consumable format**, will likely help us help you.

Comment: If you need to dynamically target different columns in the UPDATE, you'll need Dynamic SQL. Can't be done in a normal query.

Comment: Like they stated above, you'll need dynamic SQL. Think of your case statements as a simple IF ELSE for what that specific column will return for data, not for which column to return data in

Comment: Just assign a value to each column using an expression that leaves the column unchanged if that is your requirement: `... set I.CA_Status1 = case when I.CA_Status1 is NULL then "7".StatusCode else I.CA_Status1 end, I.CA_Status2 = case ... else I.CA.Status2 end, ...`."

Comment: In truth, with 4 status columns perhaps the real problem is your design and that it's denormalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the conditions that determine whether or not a particular column is updated are related, selecting the target column could be done in a `CROSS APPLY`. This would simplify the resulting assignments, making them consistent and easier to read.

```
UPDATE I
SET
    CA_Status1 = CASE WHEN S.Selector = 1 THEN "7".StatusCode ELSE I.CA_Status1 END,
    CA_Status2 = CASE WHEN S.Selector = 2 THEN "7".StatusCode ELSE I.CA_Status2 END,
    CA_Status3 = CASE WHEN S.Selector = 3 THEN "7".StatusCode ELSE I.CA_Status3 END,
    CA_Status4 = CASE WHEN S.Selector = 4 THEN "7".StatusCode ELSE I.CA_Status4 END,
    ENC = "7".ActionCode
FROM dbo.Out_P I 
INNER JOIN #TempOut_P "7" 
    ON I.ID = "7".Number 
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Selector = CASE
        WHEN I.CA_Status1 IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN I.CA_Status2 IS NULL THEN 2
        WHEN I.CA_Status3 IS NULL THEN 3
        WHEN I.CA_Status4 IS NULL THEN 4
        END
) S
```